# How do I tidy up my dependency injection?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Still pretty new to angular, let me know if I'm asking a silly question! Thanks.

I would like to tidy up my app.js file that instantiates the angular module in my rails application. It is currently a huge list that looks something like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute'
, 'ngAnimate'
, 'ngSanitize'
, 'ngCookies'
, 'http-auth-interceptor'
, 'angularFileUpload'
, 'underscore'
, 'angulartics'
, 'angulartics.google.analytics'
, 'angulartics.mixpanel'
, 'angular-loading-bar'
, 'mm.foundation'

, 'directives.dateInput'
, 'directives.elementResize'
, 'directives.calendar.calendarResize'
, 'directives.dayCalendar'
, 'directives.ngEnter'
, 'directives.datePicker'
// ....... and so on for filters
]);
```

Is it possible to require directives that automatically load the other directives, and filters that load the other filters, so that this list becomes more manageable?

Also, when I inject a main service in a controller/directive, can the main service automatically inject the other services?

For example:

```
app = angular.module("app")
app.service "ValidationService", (IdValidator) ->
  return

app.service "IdValidator", ->
  @validate = (value) ->
     #insert code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should split it into logical modules and make your app dependent of these modules.
For example:
Put all your directives into one module, and add this module as a dependency in your app.

You can split these modules into several files (If they fit into the same "Group")

```
angular.module('myDirectives', [
  'directives.dateInput',
  'directives.elementResize',
  'directives.calendar.calendarResize',
  'directives.dayCalendar',
  'directives.ngEnter',
  'directives.datePicker'
]);

angular.module('myApp', [
  'myDirectives',
  'analyticsModule',
  'utilsServices'
]);
```